# get value array of object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four input

```
<input type="text" class="kal" name="data[tex1]">
<input type="text" class="kal" name="data[tex2]">
<input type="text" class="kal" name="data[tex3]">
<input type="text" class="kal" name="data[tex4]">
```

Here is my jquery code :

```
var map = {};
     $(".kal").each(function() {
    map[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });

     console.log(map);

    });
```

Now in console, I receive the result like this:

> Object {data[tex1]: "ALI", data[tex2]: "JOHN", data[tex3]: "18", data[tex4]: "MOROCCO"}

How I can get values this object using jquery ?

Comment: I don't understand... _you are getting the values by jQuery_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access properties of object via bracket `[]` or `.` syntax. In your case your `map` is an object, but you can access it's properties via only `[]` syntax, because JavaScript Engine will give you error when you try to access with `.` syntax,because those names are not valid for property for using with `.` syntax.

Access via

```
map['data[tex1]']
```

Example

```js
var map = {
   'data[tex1]': 'AAA',
   'data[tex2]': 'BBB',
   'data[tex3]': 'CCC',
}; // After all your object will have this look

console.log(map['data[tex1]']);
// console.log(map.data[tex1]); this syntax will give you an error
```

Comment: Won't it be `map['data[tex1]']`, since the input names contain the string `data[texX]` ?